# How to pass value from a textbox to a function in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

My HTML:

```
<input type ="text" ng-model="contactid" >
```

I want to pass the contactId value entered in this box to a function `abc()` which is called `onclick` of submit button after the box.

How do I do this?

Comment: put `ng-model` on the tetbox than use this variable in the function

Comment: Angular has model, view and controller. Bind model to view and use model data in controller in submit handler. https://angularjs.org/

Comment: I think you should start with angular documentation as a basic...

Comment: Bind your input element with Angular modal with `ng-bind` or `ng-model`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
<form ng-controller="formCtrl">     
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="inputValue" />
    <button ng-click="abc(inputValue)"></button>
</form>
```

Or using `ng-submit` directive:

```
<form ng-controller="formCtrl" ng-submit="abc(inputValue)">     
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="inputValue" />
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

And in your `formCtrl` controller:

```
.controller('formCtrl', function () {
    $scope.inputValue = null;
    $scope.abc = function (value) {
        console.log(value);
    };
});
```

Comment: Could you also help me to solve this error i am getting:angular.js:12520 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at r.$scope.contactId (Index.html?name=3-1749:18)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:13365), <anonymous>:4:329)
    at e (angular.js:23613)
    at r.$eval (angular.js:16052)
    at r.$apply (angular.js:16152)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:23618)
    at If (angular.js:3346)
    at HTMLButtonElement.d (angular.js:3334)

Comment: You should open a new question. When doing so, besides showing the error, show also the code which gives the error.